# Convert Doc to HTML in php

Tags: php, html

I need help...I want to view a word document (.doc or docx) with HTML using php code without downloading it. I make use of this code but it didn't work... it show it as a text( no margin, paragraph, not as it was on docx)

```
<?php
function docx2text($filename) {
    return readZippedXML($filename, "word/document.xml");
}
function readZippedXML($archiveFile, $dataFile) {
    // Create new ZIP archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    // Open received archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($archiveFile)) {
        // If done, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // If found, read it to the string
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Close archive file
            $zip->close();
            // Load XML from a string
            // Skip errors and warnings
            $xml = new DOMDocument();
            $xml->loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Return data without XML formatting tags
            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    // In case of failure return empty string
    return "";
}
echo docx2text("resume.docx"); // Save this contents to file
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at libraries like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) that have the functionality to handle the format conversion from OfficeOpenXML to HTML?